# Bs.deriving Abstract getter function returns undefined when using capital names

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript

In the bucklescript doc example for bs.deriving abstract, you can get the property on you created object with `nameGet()`

This works:

```
@bs.deriving abstract]
type person = {
  name: string,
  age: int,
  job: string,
};
let joe = person(~name="Joe", ~age=20, ~job="teacher");
let name = nameGet(joe);
```

If you change it to capitalize the name key like below, your generated getter becomes `_NameGet()`:

```
type person = {
  _Name: string,
  age: int,
  job: string,
};
let joe = person(~_Name="Joe", ~age=20, ~job="teacher");
let name = _NameGet(joe);
```

In the second example, the name value comes back undefined. How can that be fixed?
example in repl:[tryreason](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=FAbQAgRgzgdAJgUwE4EsBuKB2BzABAQ2gBcl8BjIgXWCIE8AHBXRpKAe01wF5cBvYXLkz4AtggBcuKCSzYANAILYJuLEQWCAVmwiTpqHAoC%20AbmDAANgiK5tTHi3aYAFAD9hYrgCIAUmwRecriu%20MpcAEwADEGu2hDeRAjkABbIXgCU5pbWQqL2uWIA4tbOdulmPrAWbNjOHgiZoJCwiKgYOATEpBTUdIzMyE7h3HyKAPoAcnl6MoaKoSpqGrY6MwbywKbmVjbayZwOgxzhbpN53n77gcELEdHBcQlJZKlIGdk29XsHuGdFJd9ysBKjBqrUvmx9kDgEA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [bs.as] to alias the name of the key. This will apparently not change the name of the getter which will remain `_NameGet` in this case but the value no longer returns undefined.

```
[@bs.deriving abstract]
type person2 = {
  [@bs.as "Name"]
  _Name: string,
  age: int,
  job: string,
};

let john = person2(~_Name="John", ~age=20, ~job="teacher")
let namejohn = _NameGet(john);
Js.log(namejohn);
```

output: `John`

docs: [renaming fields](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/object#rename-fields)

Comment: If you're using `[@bs.as "Name"]` to rename the field, you can give it a more idiomatic name on the Reason side, e.g. `name`.